# What is missing from my code in order for the volume to be read?

Tags: java

Everything compiles and works. The program is not reading the Volume value and comes out as 0.0

===========================================================================

Write a superclass encapsulating a rectangle. A rectangle has two attributes representing the width and the height of the rectangle.  It has methods returning the perimeter and the area of the rectangle.  This class has a subclass, encapsulating a parallelepiped, or box.  A parallelepiped has a rectangle as its base, and another attribute, its length; it has two methods that calculate and return its area and volume.  You also need to include a client class (with the main method) to test these two classes.

---

```
public class Rectangle
{
   protected double width;
   protected double height;


   public Rectangle(double width, double height)
   {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
   }

   public double getWidth()
   {
      return width;
   }

   public void setWidth(double width) 
   {
      this.width = width;
   }

   public double getHeight()
   {
      return height;
   }

   public void setHeight(double height)
   {
      this.height = height;

   }

   public double getArea()
   {
      return width * height;
   }

   public double getPerimeter()
   {
      return 2 * (width + height);
   }

}
```

---

```
public class Box extends Rectangle 
{
   protected double length;

   public Box(double length)
   {
      super(length, length);
   }

   public double getLength()
   {
      return length;
   }

   public void setLength(double length)
   {
      this.length = length;
   }

   public double getVolume()
   {
      return width * height * length;
   }
}
```

---

```
public class TestRectangle 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(2,4);
      Box box = new Box(5);

      System.out.println("Rectangle:" );
      System.out.println("The area is " + rectangle.getArea());
      System.out.println("The perimeter is " +rectangle.getPerimeter());
      System.out.println("The volume is " + box.getVolume());
    }
}
```

---

No errors. Missing value for volume.

Comment: Please express yourself clearly. Zero is not a 'missing value'. You are missing `this.length = length;` in your `Box` constructor, so it is still zero, am so therefore is the volume.

Answer (score 3):

Your Box simply needs to set the length field.

```
public Box(double length)
{
   super(length, length);
   this.length = length;
}
```

Although, this assumes your Box is always going to be a cube, and not some arbitrary box shape.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are never assigning any value to the length variable of your box class. The current output of your code in your example would be the following for getVolume(): 5 * 5 * 0 which always returns 0.
Assuming your width, length, height are the same, you still need to assign the length to the variable:

```
public Box(double length)
{
   super(length, length);
   this.length = length;
}
```